# VSCode Issues with Live Server and git

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Just installed VSCode a couple of days ago and wasn't able to PUSH or PULL to GitHub with git. Or on any terminal, I've tried disabling my firewall and it does not seem to help the problem.
Whenever I try to pull or push I get this error.

> fatal: unable to access 'link': getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Also could use some help with Live Server whenever it starts I don't get any errors other than my browser saying

> The webpage at http://127.0.0.1:5500/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

I have tried to change settings of VSCode to use local IP as host and it still does not work.

Comment: Just saying, you should **never disable your firewall** unless absolutely necessary, as hackers can use that time to infect your computer and/or network.

Answer (score 0):

So I use a program called Aster to do multiple PC's on one computer at once and once I disable that I was able to get Git and Live to work.